# Opening Assets in NDK does not work

Tags: android-ndk

I am trying to access the Assets in my App. I seem to do it wrong somehow.

Example:

```
AAssetDir* dir = AAssetManager_openDir( manager, "/" );
const char* file = AAssetDir_getNextFileName( dir );
printf( "Filename %s\n", file );
AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open( manager, "/AndroidManifest.xml", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN );
printf( "Asset %p\n", asset );
```

which gives me:

```
Filename AndroidManifest.xml
Asset 0x0
```

What is the right way of accessing the Assets?

Answer (score -1):

```
AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open( manager, "AndroidManifest.xml", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN );
```

should work. Remove the **"/"** before the file name.

Comment: It does not work. I think if you leave the `/` the system assumes you are refering to a path of `/assets/...`.

Comment: Oops... You can only open "files" under assets.